Is Allied City Bank legit?
Is Allied City Bank legit?  The sign up is difficult to find, and asks for no information that normal banks do.  This bank is used by an acquaintance (no I haven’t met him) who had a large amount deposited into his account and he couldn’t do transfers because he’s in Ukraine (I know, I’m not convinced either).  He sent me his log on information and asked that I pay his car insurance and sent me the wire transfer information, he was sent the codes asked for during the transfer and I entered them.  All of this is documented through text messages.  Finally he said after 3 more transfers that show as approved he wanted to send me a large sum.  It was sent to my local bank account, which he can’t see from where he is.  It’s pending.  He received a message from Allied City Bank saying I would need to open an account with them because it was over 100k. And that the transaction was on hold and could be confiscated by the IMF. I opened an account and received an email with the account number, the password and pin.  It also required a deposit of $6k to have the pending amount transferred.  I have refused for many reasons, and now he’s afraid his money will be confiscated pending investigation.

Just take a look at this. If you have to ask - then yes, it is a scam.

"It also required a deposit of $6k to have the pending amount transferred." , "This bank is used by an acquaintance (no I haven’t met him)" These are flashing red lights with sirens going off. This is a run of the mill advanced fee scam, with maybe money laundering thrown in. Don't communicate any further with these folks. A common next step is for them to threaten to call law enforcement on you. Alert your own bank to the bogus transaction.

No, it's not a real bank. They claim to be based in California, but they don't show up in the NIC National Information Center and the IP address for the web site is in Lithuania. Anybody with $25 can set up a web site claiming to be a bank.

Even if it was a real bank, this whole scenario is made of more red flags than a red flag factory.
